# BroadcastReceiver not being instantiated

Tags: android

I have a BroadcastReceiver that is not being instantiated or called, any help on what I'm doing is appreciated.

It should be responding to wifi connection/disconnection events but isn't, and it's superclass constructor is not even being called either.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "action: " + intent.getAction());
        Log.v(TAG, "component: " + intent.getComponent());
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<action>` name is set incorrectly.  It should be: `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`.  See the "Constant Value" as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION).

Comment: Thanks this worked, though I've now got another issue :-). Warning: Declaring a broadcastreceiver for android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is deprecated for apps targeting N and higher. In general, apps should not rely on this broadcast and instead use JobScheduler or GCMNetworkManager

Comment: Yes, this is a change with Android N. The long term plan Google has is to remove all broadcast which could wake an app which is not already running. This causes a lot of power thrash which is generally unnecessary. You can register for this broadcast dynamically, though, using your activity.